# Data scraper save the results to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to make a Scraper or spider that can grap data from this code and insert the data in database:

```
<tr>
              <td class="player-player-name">
              <a href="/poker-players/14147-david-peat">David Peat</a>
              </td>
            <td><img alt="UNITED STATES" class="flag" src="/packages/flags/us-238691e8450c6bd68131f09bcf546d4a.png" title="UNITED STATES" /> Las Vegas, NV, USA</td>
            <td>$277,047</td>
              <td class="recent-cashes">
                <a href="/poker-tournaments/876-2007-mirage-poker-showdown-wpt/7540" class="event-name-link" ref="nofollow">No-Limit Hold&#x27;em Championship Event 10</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

I need also to save the flags and the links to next page. There is around 20 pages with poker players That I need to save in my Database over 2016 Poker players and statistic.

Link to page:
http://www.cardplayer.com/poker-players

Comment: Are you copying data from other website from where there you dont have access ? If its not your website, you should read this `Copyright © 2001-2016
CardPlayer.com. All rights reserved.` at below right corner

Comment: Yes I am , I need the data to build similar website

Comment: Dear Techboy : Creating similar website is good but, your question is requesting code to copying data from cardplayer is it good ? I don't know but it could be illegal I think couldn't it ?. Read this : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/copyright-explained-i-may-copy-it-right/#copyright-in-the-web

Comment: It's not illegal to collect  public served data so google search engine also to be illegal......

Comment: Voting to close as this is not a programming quesiton, but a "write code for me" request. Basically you are not only using other people's data, but also want other people to do that work for you. Nice Bluff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Like that.....

```
      <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.cardplayer.com/poker-players');

$theData = array();

foreach($html->find('.table-lined tr') as $row) {


$rowData = array();
foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {


    $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
}


$theData[] = $rowData;
}

$length = count($theData);
for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {


         echo "Player Name".$theData[$i][0]."----location".$theData[$i][1]."casino--".$theData[$i][2]."most".$theData[$i][3]."<br/>";

 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks it was exactly what i Needed :)